# Hide div when it is scrolled to the top of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide a "h1" element when its parent div reaches the top of the page then show it again when it moves down from the top using JQuery and CSS. I have tried using a scroll listener in JQuery used to toggle a class but this results in the "h1" quickly toggling between the class that is being toggled. Is there an way I can hide the div when it reaches the top of the page then show it again when it moves down?

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var distance_from_top = $("#backgroundtitle h1").offset().top;
    if (($(window)).scrollTop() > distance_from_top) {
      $("#backgroundtitle h1").toggleClass("hidetitle");
    }
    if (($(window)).scrollTop() < distance_from_top) {
      $("#backgroundtitle h1").toggleClass("hidetitle");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
 html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Myriad Set Pro", "Lucida Grande", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", "Verdana", "sans-serif";
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 100;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
#header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
#header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}
#header ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}
#header a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0 5%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#homeimage {
  background: url(Images/Home_Image.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -100;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
#background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}
#background h1 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 100;
}
#backgroundtitle {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#backgroundtitle h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#container1 {
  height: auto;
  background-color: #00A3FF;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container1 h1 {
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 5%;
  margin: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}
#container1text {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 2.5%;
  float: left;
}
#container1text p {
  font-size: large;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#homeimage">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#container1">Introduction</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="homeimage">
    <div id="background">
      <div id="backgroundtitle">
        <h1>Title</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="container1">
    <h1>Introduction</h1>
    <div id="container1text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, cumque, id, quasi iste illum dolorum libero vero voluptate labore ullam voluptatum aliquam tempore dolor molestiae debitis hic ipsam vel quidem.</p>
      <br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, dignissimos magni nulla cupiditate nisi veritatis hic ullam saepe dolor numquam recusandae assumenda aspernatur perspiciatis non similique ipsam architecto sapiente excepturi!</p>
      <br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, ducimus, atque, delectus, fugiat adipisci animi deserunt culpa doloremque ea impedit natus dolores amet veniam vitae eaque eligendi fugit dolorum hic!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is because you're not checking to see if the h1 element has the hidetitle class or not before toggling.  So ever scroll action triggers the class to toggle.  The following code checks to see if the element is at the top and if it has the hidetitle class before toggling.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var h1selector = $("#backgroundtitle h1");
        var distance_from_top = h1selector.offset().top;

        if(($(window)).scrollTop() > distance_from_top && h1selector.hasClass("hidetitle")) {
            h1selector.toggleClass("hidetitle");
        }
        else if($(window)).scrollTop() < distance_from_top && !h1selector.hasClass("hidetitle")){
            h1selector.toggleClass("hidetitle");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, however when I tried your code it hid the "h1" when the scrolling started even though it had not reached the top yet. When I then scrolled it down it did not show again.

Answer (score 2):

I would use addClass() and removeClass() for situation like this.
1. Assign an id to your title ie: id="title"
2. In your style set #title.hideTitle{display:none;}  //this will overwrite the other styling rules you have.
3. Then in your javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).scroll(function() {
      if($(window).scrollTop() > 301) {
          $("#backgroundtitle h1").addClass("hideTitle");
      }else{
        $("#backgroundtitle h1").removeClass("hideTitle");
      }
  });
});
</script>
```

Let me know what you think ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however this still results in the "h1" toggling its class  when it is scrolled resulting in the "h1" flashing.

Comment: I set the if statement to have a fixed number 301 which is the position of your h1.  If you use a fixed number instead of a variable it should solve the problem.